# Telegram: Launching web app from inline button

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

I`m trying to launch web app from inline button in telegram. Using pure api. Here is a simplified code sample:

```
$inline .= '[{"text":"'.$row['text'].'","web_app":{"url":"'.$row['val'].'"},"callback_data":"setitem_'.$toid.'"}]';
...
$inline = '{"inline_keyboard":['.$inline.']}';
sendMsg($bot['token'],$chatId,"Нажмите для запуска:", ["reply_markup"=>$inline]);
```

Buttons appear under message but web app don`t launching.

However tried to do same from `menu` button is working:

```
  if ($bot['menubtntext'] && $bot['menubtnurl']) {
    $POST = [
        'menu_button' => '{"type":"web_app","text":"'.tgescape($bot['menubtntext']).'","web_app":{"url":"'.$bot['menubtnurl'].'"}}'
    ];
  }
  $ch = curl_init($TgAPI.'bot'.strip_tags($bot['token']).'/setChatMenuButton');
  curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
      CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
      CURLOPT_POST => 1,
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $POST,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT    => 60
  ));
  $output = curl_exec($ch);
  $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  curl_close($ch);
```

Whats the problem with inline button? I see buttons, but they don`t open any https url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

callback_data incompatible with web_app
It working like this:

```
$inline[] = [['text'=>tgescape($row['text']), 'web_app' => ['url' => $row['val']]]];
$inline = '{"inline_keyboard":'.json_encode($inline).'}';
sendMsg($bot['token'],$chatId,"Нажмите для запуска:", ["reply_markup"=>$inline]);
```

Comment: У меня почему-то ошибка: {"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: BUTTON_TYPE_INVALID"}. Вот с этим кодом
$msgsum['text'] = "Сканируйте QR код";
$msgsum["reply_markup"] = json_encode([
    "inline_keyboard" => [
        [["text"=>"qrcode","web_app"=>["url"=>$url]]]
]]);
tlgrm("sendMessage", $msgsum, $channel);